# HTML input type submit strange behavior after adding a custom class

Tags: html, css, forms, jsp, submit

I got a form on my page with a submit button:

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input id="searchTerm" type="text" name="searchterm" class="search-field"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When I click on the button I sucessfuly submit the form and trigger jQuery function:

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function() {
    some code...
});
```

With no reason, when I add a custom class to change the button appearance it stops trigering submit function, as it was before:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-search"/>
```

The class adds the folowing properties:

```
#search .main .search-bar .submit-search {
    margin-top: 2.3rem;
}

#search .main .search-bar .submit-search {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("../../css/sprites/search-submit-icon.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    border: medium none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
}
```

I will appreciate any ideas to make this working.

Comment: I do not think your problem has anything to do with the class, I see you have two functions on that button? One on the click event and one on the form submit. Trying removing the onclick and check if the on submit function is working

Comment: You are missing an opening `<` on your text input

Comment: when I remove onClick function from the button, the submit function still do not work if the class is applied. Both functions work only if I remove the class from the button. I corrected the question for the latest experience.

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions executing when the button is clicked. First it executes the function checkTextField() which is on the click event then when it finishes it executes, other function which is on the form submit event. I think this is not a good idea. You should remove the onclick function and add it to the on form submit.

Comment: Of course this can be done. But anyway if I resign from onClick function from the button, the submit function still do not work if the class is applied. Both functions work only if I remove the class from the button. I corrected the question for the latest experience.

Comment: I have tested your code, and the button works with the css class. Css can not break a js script. Your problem is somewhere in the js script. Maybe you have another event handler for that class?

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else, on in other javascript provided by layout team.

Comment: Try renaming the class to make sure that no js code is handled on that one.